# Jsoup: How to open links in a parsed html in the same activity

Tags: android, android-intent, jsoup, android-volley

I am building an app for my blog and I am using Volley to load the URL and Jsoup to parse it.

**The Sample Html**

```
<body class="sin">
    <div class="ks">
        <div class="wrap">

            <div class="content-right-sidebar-wrap">
                <main class="content">

                    //A lot of unneeded tags

                    <article class="post-1989009 post type-post post" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
                        <header class="post-header">
                            <h1 class="post-title" itemprop="headline">Yet Another 6GB RAM Phone: LeEco Le Max 2 Unveiled</h1>
                        </header>

                        //A lot of unneeded tags

                        <div class="post-content" itemprop="text">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam nec nisi lectus. In consectetur nunc accumsan dui molestie, ut ultricies elit lobortis.
                                <a href="https://website.com/2002/03/odales-cursus-sed-eget-dolor.html">odales cursus sed eget dolor</a> Etiam arcu risus, aliquet porta pharetra non, pharetra in dui..
                            </p>

                            <p>
                                <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-19289" src="https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2002/04/image-39.jpeg" alt="LeEco Le Max 2" width="800" height="450" srcset="https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2002/09/gutter-bkan.jpeg 800w, https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2002/09/gutter-bkan-300x169.jpeg 300w, https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2002/09/gutter-bkan-768x432.jpeg 768w, https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2002/09/gutter-bkan-265x150.jpeg 265w, https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2002/09/gutter-bkan-320x180.jpeg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 800px">
                            </p>
                            <p>Sed porta aliquet sollicitudin. Vivamus commodo placerat sapien vitae interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</p>

                            <p> eu massa volutpat, volutpat ipsum id, maximus risus. Etiam maximus lobortis enim sed eleifend. Integer imperdiet, augue accumsan ultricies faucibus, orci orci porttitor velit, semper fringilla</p>

                                <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-19290" src="https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2002/07/guter-lop.jpeg" alt="LeEco Le Max 2" width="728" height="324" srcset="https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2002/07/guter-lop.jpeg 728w, https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2002/07/guter-lop-300x134.jpeg 300w" sizes="(max-width: 728px) 100vw, 728px">
                            </p>
                            <p>Sed nec nunc nec eros vulputate vehicula. Duis laoreet ex vel auctor finibus. Sed semper blandit massa, at molestie ligula vestibulum in. Nulla vestibulum viverra risus vitae fringilla</p>

                            <h2>Luccuii</h2>
                            <p>Leuismod ultrices libero at consequat. Quisque vestibulum vulputate vehicula. Vivamus posuere nibh tincidunt tristique faucibus. Integer sed vulputate dui, a luctus sem. Suspendisse potenti.</p>

                        </div>
                     //Skipped the closing tags
```

**My Activity**

```
public class PostDetails extends AppCompatActivity{

 private final String TAG = "PostDetails";
 private AlertDialog internetDialog;

 private String postData;


 protected com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader mImageLoader;


 TextView postTitle, postContent;


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_details);

     showDialog();

     postTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dpost_title);
     postContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dpost_content);
     postContent.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

     DisplayImageOptions defaultoptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
             .cacheInMemory(true)
             .cacheOnDisk(true)
             .build();
     ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
             .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultoptions)
             .writeDebugLogs()
             .build();


     mImageLoader = com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.getInstance();
     mImageLoader.init(config);

     ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
     if (actionBar != null) {
         actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     }



     if (savedInstanceState != null) {


              postData = savedInstanceState.getString("postData");
         if (postData != null) {
             parseHtml(postData);
         } else {
             loadPost();
         }



     } else {
         if (NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(this)) {
             //Calling method to load posts
             loadPost();
         } else {
             internetDialog.show();
         }
     }
 }

 private void showDialog() {
     internetDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PostDetails.this)
             .setCancelable(false)
             .setMessage(R.string.alert_mess_det)
             .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_retry, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     if (!NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(PostDetails.this)) {
                         if (internetDialog != null && internetDialog.isShowing()) {
                             internetDialog.dismiss();
                             internetDialog = null;
                             showDialog();
                             internetDialog.show();
                         }
                     } else {
                         loadPost();
                     }

                 }
             })
             .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     finish();

                 }
             })
             .create();
 }

 private void loadPost() {
     Log.d(TAG, "loadPost called");

     final ProgressBar progressBar;
     progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_circle);
     progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


     String news_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("PostId");
     Log.d(TAG, "You clicked post id " + news_id);

     StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(news_id,
             new Response.Listener<String>() {
                 @Override
                 public void onResponse(String response) {
                     //Log.d("Debug", response.toString());
                     if (progressBar != null) {
                         progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     }
                     parseHtml(response);
                     postData = response;


                 }
             },
             new Response.ErrorListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                     VolleyLog.d("", "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                     if (progressBar != null) {
                         progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     }

                     final  AlertDialog.Builder sthWrongAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(PostDetails.this);
                     sthWrongAlert.setCancelable(false);
                     sthWrongAlert.setMessage(R.string.sth_wrongme_det);
                     sthWrongAlert.setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_retry, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             if (!NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(PostDetails.this)) {
                                 internetDialog.show();
                             } else {
                                 loadPost();
                             }

                         }
                     });
                     sthWrongAlert.setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             finish();
                         }
                     });
                     sthWrongAlert.show();
                 }
             });

     //Creating requestqueue
     RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

     //Adding request queue
     requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


 }

 private void parseHtml(String response) {
     Log.d(TAG, "parsinghtml");
     Document document = Jsoup.parse(response);
     String post_title = document.select("h1.post-title").first().text();
     String post_content = document.select("div.post-content").first().html();


     postTitle.setText(post_title);
     Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(post_content, new UILImageGetter(postContent, this), null );
     postContent.setText(spanned);

     //Unhiding views
     postTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     postContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
 }

 @Override
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
     super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
     outState.putString("postData", postData);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
     onBackPressed();
     return true;
 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy();
     Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy called");
     mImageLoader.destroy();
 }
```

}

The text dispalyed in `postContent` has links, links that leads to another posts.

So what I want is that when the link (let's call it **link A**) is clicked this same activity (**PostDetail**) gets the url of the clicked link and parses it.

And when the content of **link A** has been loaded and parsed, it's `postContent` also contains links to other posts. And when these links are clicked the same activity (**PostDetail**) should also load and parse it.

please, how do I achieve this?

**Note 1:** The html  of the posts pages have the same format so the code above can succesfully parse it.

**Note 2:** Truthfully, there are other links apart from my post links that exists in `postContent` (e.g links to other websites) but the links that leads to posts in my blog starts with "https://website.com/20" (e.g "https://website.com/2013/12/1/post-title", "https://website.com/2007/11/21/another-post-title").

So I am thinking of checking if the links starts with "https://website.com/20", if yes load it in this activity; if no, implicint intent the user to select a browser.

Comment: Use Linkify: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html  Documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html

Comment: i am trying to open hyperlinks in same activity after parsing with jsoup ,if you found the solution please post it